# Showing stochastic dominance given the expectation of two Poisson R.V.'s

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis, poisson-distribution

Suppose that I have two Poisson random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ with means $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively. If I know $\lambda_2 > \lambda_1$ then does it follow that $ X_1 \preceq_{st} X_2$?

So far what I have is the following:
\begin{align*}
X_1 \preceq_{st} X_2 &\iff P \lbrace X_1 > t \rbrace \leq P \lbrace X_2 > t  \rbrace ~~~~~~~ -\infty < t < \infty \\
&\iff 1 - e^{-\lambda_1} \sum_{i = 0}^t \dfrac{\lambda^i_1}{i!} \leq 1 - e^{-\lambda_2} \sum_{i = 0}^t \dfrac{\lambda^i_2}{i!}  \\
&\iff  - e^{-\lambda_1} \sum_{i = 0}^t \dfrac{\lambda^i_1}{i!} \leq  - e^{-\lambda_2} \sum_{i = 0}^t \dfrac{\lambda^i_2}{i!}  \\
&\iff  e^{-\lambda_2} \sum_{i = 0}^t \dfrac{\lambda^i_2}{i!} \leq  e^{-\lambda_1} \sum_{i = 0}^t \dfrac{\lambda^i_1}{i!} \\
&\iff \color{red}{\lambda_1 < \lambda_2} ~~~ (*)\\
\end{align*}
However I am not sure how solid the ending is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The ending would need to establish that $e^{-\lambda} \sum_{i=0}^t \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}$ is decreasing in $\lambda$ (and, if true, would end with $\lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2$ rather than strict inequality). An alternative approach is to say $X_2 \geq \tilde{X}_2 = \sum_{i=1}^{X_2}A_i$ (with $\tilde{X}_2=0$ if $X_2=0$) where $\{A_i\}$ are independent of $X_2$ and i.i.d. Bernoulli with prob $\lambda_1/\lambda_2$.  That is, thin the Poisson variable $X_2$ to a smaller one by probabilisitically including each of the $X_2$ arrivals.

Comment: @Michael would there be a way for me to format an argument based off the idea that $\mathbb{E} (X)$ is strictly increasing if $X$ is a Poisson RV?

Answer (score 3):

$\lambda_1\le\lambda_2 \implies X_1\preceq_{st}X_2$: Suppose that randon variables $X_1, Z$ are independent, $\mathsf{P}(Z\ge0)=1$ and $X_2=X_1+Z$, then
$X_1\preceq_{st} X_2$. To prove this just use convolution formula as following
$$  F_{X_2}(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_Z(t-s)dF_{X_1}(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}F_Z(t-s)dF_{X_1}(s)\le \int_{-\infty}^{t}dF_{X_1}(s)=F_{X_1}(t), \qquad \forall t.$$
Now let $X_1\sim P(\lambda_1), Z\sim P(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)$ where $X_1$ and $Z$ are independent. Then $X_2\sim P(\lambda_2)$ and
$$   X_1\preceq_{st} X_2. $$

$X_1\preceq_{st}X_2 \implies \lambda_1\le \lambda_2$:
$$ \lambda_1=\mathsf{E}[X_1]=\int_0^\infty F(X_1>t)dt\le \int_0^\infty F(X_2>t)dt=\mathsf{E}[X_2]=\lambda_2.$$